# "as well" in a negative sentence

Tags: usage, negation

Is it correct to use "*as well*" to give an additional condition for which something is *not* happening?

Example:

> [*sentence explaining that no solution exists*] if the function is linear. For a non-linear function as well, no solution exists if...''

In a non-scientific text, I resort to a formulation with "neither", but all the possibilities I find involve either reordering the words or unnatural inversion of some words in the sentence : *Neither for non-linear functions do solutions exist...* Here for the ease of following our (otherwise rather involve) reasoning, I feel that it its important to begin the sentence by "*`[one or 2 words]` non-linear function ...*"

Any suggestion? Or is *as well* fine in a text where language quality is not the point?

Comment: You could use "likewise" or "in the same way" or "similarly" or a wide variety of alternatives.

Comment: _Neither_ does indeed feel awkward. _Either_ can easily be used, though: "For a non-linear function, no solution exists _either_ if...''

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, using "as well" to provide an additional negative condition is possible. However, using "as well" in your example might be slightly confusing for the reader. A clearer alternative would be to use "also" or "too" instead.

For example:

> [sentence explaining that no solution exists] if the function is
> linear. For non-linear functions **too**, no solution exists if...

or

> [sentence explaining that no solution exists] if the function is
> linear. For non-linear functions **also**, no solution exists if...

Both "too" and "also" provide a clearer indication that you're referring to an additional condition where something is not happening. Keep in mind that using "also" is more formal than using "too".

If you want to focus on language quality, my recommendation would be to rephrase the sentence to improve clarity and flow. One possible way to rewrite the example is:

> [sentence explaining that no solution exists] if the function is
> linear. Similarly, for non-linear functions, no solution exists if...

By using "similarly," you facilitate an even clearer connection between the two conditions, emphasizing that the lack of a solution applies to both linear and non-linear functions.

Comment: This stucture corresponds to the choice I've finally made, using 'likewise'. Indeed it balances between a clear parallelism of the results (which are 'alike') while keeping 'non-linear function' in clear opposition to 'linear' ones.